# using std::valarray and std::slice to copy stridden data

Tags: c++, stl, stdvector, valarray, range-v3

I'm trying efficiently to copy stridden data. Consider following function signature

```
void foo(Array& input, Buffer& U, Buffer& V)
```

where Buffer and Array are

```
using Buffer = std::vector<uint8_t>;
using Array = std::valarray<uint8_t>;
```

Now, depending on constness of input I can slice the `valarray` and get another `valarray` or `slice_array`. Getting sliced `valarray` harms performance (copy). Is there a way to copy sliced data using the `slice_array`?

My naïve implementation

```
void foo(Array& input, Buffer& U, Buffer& V)
{
    Array Uslice = input[std::slice(0, input.size() / 2, 2)];
    Array Vslice = input[std::slice(0 + 1, input.size() / 2, 2)];

    std::copy(std::begin(Uslice), std::end(Uslice), U.begin());
    std::copy(std::begin(Vslice), std::end(Vslice), V.begin());
}
```

However, this implementation is slower than just looping over the input and assigning values by index.

BTW, I'm not bound to valarray, in case you have better ideas what container to use

EDIT001: Second thought, Range-V3 may be handy in this case, with its `ranges::v3::view::stride`, however I cant find any example of how to use it

EDIT002: Managed to get ranges working. It is terribly slow, 20 times slower than simple for loop.

```
void foo(Buffer& input, Buffer& U, Buffer& V)
{
    V = ranges::move(input | ranges::v3::view::slice(0ull, input.size()) | ranges::v3::view::stride(2));
    U = ranges::move(input | ranges::v3::view::slice(1ull, input.size()) | ranges::v3::view::stride(2));
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?